# Pre-answer raw_input for Openvpn

Tags: python, automation, passwords, openvpn

How would I be able to allow automatic population of the password required when opening the openvpn scrip? Even if just for testing it was supplied as a string

```
import subprocess

def connect():
subprocess.call(["sudo","openvpn", "BMHQ-client.conf"])

connect()
```

This would prompt for a password however I would like the simplest way to not have to enter that password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can populate it by sticking your creds into another file and calling that from your config.

add this line to your config `auth-user-pass login.conf`

and create another file with your credits in it called login.conf.

`Username`

`password`

Comment: I need to add its not exactly secure as your credentials will be in a file in clear text. You could create some basic obfuscation if you want and then un-obfuscate it in your script. Or you could create a file with your creds in clear text in your script from some obfuscated strings?

Comment: [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/2/library/hashlib.html) handles sha256 so that would do it for you. Dont use MD5 or SHA1 they are becoming obsolete due to the amount of rainbow tables out there (specially if your pass is weak)

Comment: Working my way there, thanks for the comments it really helps us beginners! Will let you know how it goes.

Comment: yeah tell me about it, im a beginner myself ^_^. if you have anymore questions fire away ;) if i can help i will.

Comment: I realize this is not very secure however this seemed to solve my immediate request, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Arr I see what you mean now. You want to per-populate the sudo password.

use the -S option for sudo

so could do something like the below in your script. (again not very secure)

`echo mypassword | sudo -S command`